# Are the three Gorgon sisters blood related?

Tags: one-piece

Boa Hancock is considered to be the most beautiful woman in the world of One Piece, but her sisters are totally different.

[image: Boa Hancock and her sisters]

Are they blood related sisters?

> Or perhaps something happened during their time as a slave?

Comment: Check the image of the sisters of the time when they were slaves. All the three of them look pretty similar. I'll come up with a proper answer. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those 3 girls are definitely blood related. Boa Hancock explains her tragedy in [episode 415](http://www.watchonepiece.us/one-piece-episode-415-english-sub/) in which we can see the 3 girls in their childhood and early teen years and they definitely look similar. Their different characteristics are probably because of,

- just being different:- even in real life siblings have different traits which grow as they mature.
- different devil fruits:- we know that Boa Hancock ate [Mero Mero No Mi](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Mero_Mero_no_Mi) fruit (Paramecia type), and her sisters ate Hebi Hebi No Mi fruits (Zoan type), [Hebi Hebi No Mi, Model Anaconda](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Hebi_Hebi_no_Mi,_Model%3a_Anaconda) (Boa Sandersonia) and [Hebi Hebi No Mi, Model King Cobra](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Hebi_Hebi_no_Mi,_Model%3a_King_Cobra) (Boa Marigold).

Answer (score 2):

They are blood related. Proof found on the [One piece wiki](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Gorgon_Sisters)

I personally think Oda made them different from each other to make it more interesting for the viewers.

Answer (score 0):

The kuja go out and have sex with men, just to get pregnant. Then they come back and have the children. So the sisters probably have the same mom, but different dads.

Comment: Hi. If you are not sure or if this is a theory based on facts, try to edit it and include sources/references you used to arrived at that answer before posting. If this is based on information found in the manga/anime, please specify where you found it. Thanks!